# Kubuntu 16.10 GUI cannot load, after updates were installed

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

I've been using Kubuntu for about 6 months.  I had not rebooted in about a month and noticed that there were approximately over 100 updates waiting to be installed.  After **installing updates**, the computer appeared to reboot OK but was **unable to load the default GUI desktop**.  At that point, the screen goes blank and I press the following keys to enter the terminal:

```
ctrl + alt + F1
```

I tried many recommendations that I found on the web but none have worked so far, including an NVidia fix since I have an NVidia GeForce 210 card.  By typing the following, nothing is echoed which was even more confusing to me:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

**UPDATE**

I decided to see if my **motherboard's built in VGA adapter** would work and after plugging in a VGA monitor, I have full GUI access.  The **problem must be with an NVidia driver that was recently updated**.

**THE SOLUTION**

Since I have GUI access via the VGA port (built into motherboard) only, I came to the conclusion that it was in fact my NVidia driver causing the problem, so I **removed the 'NVidia X Server Settings'**.  Then I disconnected my built in VGA and connected the computer to my NVidia PCI Express card using my other HDMI monitor.  It worked but the resolution was very low.  I went to NVidia's website and **downloaded the latest Linux .run file for my card**.  After running the installation, I was then able to use my high definition PCI Express card.